# Automatic initialization is only supported on root forms. You should set the "auto_initialize" option to false on the field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, events, sonata-admin

I'm having the following error in my Symfony2 project:

> Automatic initialization is only supported on root forms. You should set the "auto_initialize" option to false on the field "descriptionEN".

I'm using the [Sonata Admin Bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/index.html). I would like to **populate** a **text field** in my form before rendering the form. So I am using the form event `PRE_SET_DATA` . In Sonata you only have prePersist & preUpdate so I am doing it like this:

```
// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('tag', 'text', array('label' => 'Tag'))
        ->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Beschrijving'))
        ->add('content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Tekst', 'attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'), 'help' =>
            'Schrijf 2 paragrafen onder elkaar, deze worden naast elkaar geplaatst op de website.'))
        ->add('files', 'file', array('required' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'help' =>
            '<b>Home:</b> 1277×670.png<br><b>Gallerij:</b> 1284×110.jpg<br><b>Diensten:</b> 1282×375.jpg<br><b>Footer:</b> 1281×375.jpg'))
    ;

    $builder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder();
    $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();

    $func = function (FormEvent $e) use ($factory) {
        $form = $e->getForm();
        $page = $e->getData();

        $pageLocale = $this->getSubject();
        $pageID = $pageLocale->getPageId();

        if($pageID === null)
        {
            return;
        }

        $form->add($factory->createNamed('descriptionEN', 'text', array(
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'label' => 'Beschrijving Engels',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($pageID) {
                return $repository->getDescriptionEN($pageID);
        }
        )));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $func);

}
```

The strange thing is I'm getting the error that **auto_initialize** should be **false** when I've specifically set it to false ... . I'm definitely sure that's the field causing problems because when I comment the field I get no errors.

What could be another reason causing this?

Answer (score 3):

The array of options is the fourth parameter of the function `createNamed`

```
$form->add($factory->createNamed('descriptionEN', 'text', null, array(
        'auto_initialize' => false,
        'label' => 'Beschrijving Engels',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($pageID) {
            return $repository->getDescriptionEN($pageID);
    }
```